# Apache fop, XSL FO: Occasionally adds empty page at the end of flow in page sequence (not the last one)

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Using apache-fop 1.0  also tried 2.1 with the same behaviour.

My Questions:

- Why is the empty page generated?
- How can the page numbering be as
  weird as Page 4 of 3?
- How can I omit the empty page, while keeping
  the page numbering?

The Scenario:

Using the following XSL **fop inserts occasionally an empty** page at the end of the page flow. This also leads to **strange page numbering like Page 4 of 3 Pages**.

The are 3 different page-sequences and for each sequence the page numbering should start with 1. The first should just add something like a cover page. The second page-sequence should render some table data using different footers on first-page, last-page and others. The third page-sequence should represent something like a copy of page-sequence two, having the same output but in reality having slightly different headers and/or footers.

However, **at the end of each sequence an empty blank page is insert - except for the last page-sequence**.

Each page-sequence for itself (the others commented out) is working fine, without generating the empty page.

My XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                version="1.0"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/fop/src/foschema/fop.xsd?view=co">


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-cover"
                                       page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin="1cm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="body"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>

                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-first"
                                       page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin="1cm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="body" space-before="11cm" space-after="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="header-first" extent="11cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="footer-first" extent="3cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>


                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-other"
                                       page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin="1cm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="body" space-before="3cm" space-after="5cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="header-other" extent="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="footer-other" extent="5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>


                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-last"
                                       page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin="1cm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="body" space-before="3cm" space-after="5cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="header-last" extent="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="footer-last" extent="5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>


                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="A4-multi">
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="A4-first"/>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="rest" master-reference="A4-other"/>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="last" master-reference="A4-last"/>
                    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>


                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="A4-very-first">
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="A4-cover"/>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="rest" master-reference="A4-other"/>
                    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>



            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-very-first" initial-page-number="1">
                <fo:flow flow-name="body">
                    <fo:block>just the first page</fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-multi" initial-page-number="1">

                <xsl:call-template name="header-first"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="header-other"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="header-last"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="footer-first"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="footer-other"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="footer-last"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="flow-1"/>
            </fo:page-sequence>


            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-multi" initial-page-number="1">

                <xsl:call-template name="header-first"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="header-other"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="header-last"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="footer-first"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="footer-other"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="footer-last"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="flow-2"/>

            </fo:page-sequence>


        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="flow-1">
        <fo:flow flow-name="body">
            <xsl:call-template name="item-table"/>
            <fo:block id="last-page-flow-1"></fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- just a copy of flow 1-->
    <xsl:template name="flow-2">
        <fo:flow flow-name="body">
            <xsl:call-template name="item-table"/>
            <fo:block id="last-page-flow-2"></fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- table -->
    <xsl:template name="item-table">
        <fo:table width="100%" border="1px solid black" table-layout="fixed">
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>

            <fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-row border="1px solid red">
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>Item: header</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-header>

            <fo:table-footer>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="1px solid blue">
                        <fo:block>Item: footer</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-footer>

            <fo:table-body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="list"/>
            </fo:table-body>

        </fo:table>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- row -->
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell border-bottom="1px dashed black">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="out"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- the different headers  -->
    <xsl:template name="header-initial">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="header-initial">
            <fo:table background-color="yellow" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell height="4cm">
                            <fo:block>Header first page</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="header-first">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="header-first">
            <fo:table background-color="yellow" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell height="11cm">
                            <fo:block>Header first page</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="header-other">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="header-other">
            <fo:table background-color="red" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell height="3cm">
                            <fo:block>Header other pages</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="header-last">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="header-last">
            <fo:table background-color="blue" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell height="3cm">
                            <fo:block>Header last page</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- the different footers  -->
    <xsl:template name="footer-initial">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-initial">
            <fo:table background-color="orange" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell height="106mm">
                            <fo:block>Footer initial page - ESR</fo:block>
                            <fo:block>P<fo:page-number/>/
                                <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page-flow-1"/>
                                <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page-flow-2"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="footer-first">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-first">
            <fo:table background-color="yellow" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell height="3cm">
                            <fo:block>Footer first page</fo:block>
                            <fo:block>Page
                                <fo:page-number/>
                                of
                                <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page-flow-1"/>
                                <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page-flow-2"/>
                                Pages
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="footer-other">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-other">
            <fo:table background-color="red" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell height="5cm">
                            <fo:block>Footer other pages</fo:block>
                            <fo:block>Page
                                <fo:page-number/>
                                of
                                <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page-flow-1"/>
                                <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page-flow-2"/>
                                Pages
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>

        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="footer-last">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="footer-last">
            <fo:table background-color="blue" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell height="5cm">
                            <fo:block>Footer last page</fo:block>
                            <fo:block>Page<fo:page-number/>of
                                <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page-flow-1"/>
                                <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="last-page-flow-2"/>
                                Pages
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML with some simple data

```
<list>

<item>
    <out>Test1</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test2</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test3</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test4</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test5</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test6</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test7</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test8</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test9</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test10</out>
</item>

<item>
    <out>Test11</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test12</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test13</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test14</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test15</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test16</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test17</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test18</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test19</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test20</out>
</item>

<item>
    <out>Test21</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test22</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test23 -- last on page-first</out>
</item>

<!-- max items on first page -->
<item>
    <out>Test24 -- first on page-other/page-last</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test25</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test26</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test27</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test28</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test29</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test30</out>
</item>

<item>
    <out>Test31</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test32</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test33</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test34</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test35</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test36</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test37</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test38</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test39</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test40</out>
</item>

<item>
    <out>Test41</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test42</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test43</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test44</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test45</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test46</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test47</out>
</item>

<item>
    <out>Test48</out>
</item>

<item>
    <out>Test49</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test50</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test51</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test52</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test53</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test54</out>
</item>

<item>
    <out>Test55</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test56</out>
</item>
<item>
    <out>Test57 - last on page-other</out>
</item>

<item>
    <out>Test58 -first on page-last</out>
</item>
```

Empty Page (red) after last page of page-sequence two (blue), 
[image]

Comment: one possible typo `<fo:block id="last-page-flow-23">` probably ..-flow-2? - What fop version are you using?

Comment: You are right, that's a typo, but with no effect to the generated output. As mentioned in the post, the version actually is 1.0, but I also tried 2.1 with the same result. I will correct the typo, since it has no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gotit. The force-page-count on a page-sequence if being "auto" will "Force it to be an even-page if the initial-page-number of the next page-sequence is odd" [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/#force-page-count)

So as your third page-sequence has initial-page-number 1 (odd), but the last page of the second is actually 5 (or 3 if we omit the very first) (also odd), so one page will be added, obviously not even treating it as last (not nice). It will display page 4 *(as it is the 4th)* of 3 *(as the referenced id is on page 3)*.

The way around it is adding a

`force-page-count="no-force"`

attribute to the `fo:page-sequence`s

**Edit**

If you also had a `blank-or-not-blank="blank"` conditional-page-master-reference with no header or footer, then no page number would appear on that added page. But I understand you rather not had it at all.

Comment: Wow! Thanks la lot. That did it. I never would have expected the default behaviour of force-page-count and therefore always searched in the wrong direction. Also beeing confused about fop adding an empty page at the end of a  page-sequence but not using the conditional-page-master-reference defined for the last page in that sequence.

Comment: Yes, could be considered at least a trap in the design. However, some reading of specs sometimes puts an idea in the back of the head for a hook for further searching. Your question was really good and made it easy to reproduce.